# download a polygone instead of bbox from OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, 3d-model

I want to download a 3d model from a list of coordinates. The API documentation only says that you can download a bbox, but looking at the overpassAPI documentation you can download all the nodes within that polygon [doc](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.7#Using_a_polygon_to_download_data).

Can you download directly a polygon, or can you transform the csv file with the list of nodes to an osm file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a program which can clip the osm based in polygon.
[There its](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Clipping_based_on_a_Polygon)